# How should i pass $scope value to function in haml template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, haml

I am using haml templates with angular js. While template rendering i want to create a function call on div using ng-click. It is working fine without parameter but when I am passing a parameter to function it behaving like as below for two cases.

```
%div.sitesContainer
  .wrapper
    %div.site{"ng-repeat"=>"site in sites",'ng-click'=>"siteBlockclick({{site.id}})"}
      %span
        {{site.name}}
```

Then it is giving me error **Syntax Error: Token 'site.id' is unexpected** But I inspect div it is showing `ng-click="siteBlockclick(BWN)"` means value is coming but single quotes are missing.

```
%div.sitesContainer
  .wrapper
    %div.site{"ng-repeat"=>"site in sites",'ng-click'=>"siteBlockclick('{{site.id}}')"}
      %span
        {{site.name}}
```

If I given single quotes it is printing then it is making call like **ng-click="siteBlockclick('{{site.id}}')"**

How should I concat it so that It will work for me ?

I want something like **ng-click="siteBlockclick('BWN')** after inspect

Any help appreciated.

Comment: in HAML the bracket has meaning... maybe you can escape it: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#escaped-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an `ng-click`, you don't need to interpolate (use `{{ }}`.

So, this should work for you:

```
%div.sitesContainer
  .wrapper
    %div.site{"ng-repeat"=>"site in sites",'ng-click'=>"siteBlockclick(site.id)"}
      %span
        {{site.name}}
```

the `ng-repeat` creates each `site` in scope and the `ng-click` accesses that scope directly.